# httpClientBuilder cannot be resolved in Java

Tags: java, ssl

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory).build();
```

The HttpClientBuilder cannot be resolved. Anyone any idea how to fix this?

Comment: It depends where do you want to get your HttpClient from. Did you write it yourself? Do you try to use existing outside implementation of HttpClient?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either download the Apache HttpClient libraries from https://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi and add the jars to your project or add the maven dependancy:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: i get this error when running code: com.ibm.jsse2.util.j: Certificate chaining error

Comment: If your still having a problem finding the HttpClientBuilder class, is it a compile time problem or a run-time problem. For a compile time problem edit your question with details on what kind of project it is and how you tried to add the jars to your project. For a run time error edit the question and explain the exact command you are using to run it. If finding the class is no longer a problem and there is a new Certificate chaining problem then I would suggest creating a new question with certificate chaining in the title and the complete text of exception with stack trace.